# Как отправлять sms из php бесплатно?

Tags: php, mobile, sms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, *бесплатный* метод или скрипт для отправки sms из PHP сайта для верификации мобильного телефона, указанного пользователем.

Comment: Отправка смс почти всегда и везде стоит денег, поэтому вряд ли найдётся сервис, который вы сможете бесплатно использовать в *рабочем* режиме. При небольшом объёме можете подключить к серверу свой телефон и отправлять смс через него с помощью какого-то софта. И самостоятельно платить за сотовый контракт.

Answer (score 3):

Можете использовать Андроид телефон.

1. В php генерируете СМС и сохраняете в базу
2. Создаете ссылку, которое дает что нужно отправить и кому
3. Создаете Andorid приложение, которое периодически проверяет данные из сервера с функции (2)
4. Если нужно что то отправить, берет из сервера (2) и отправляет через СМС (симку)

Есть такой же метод, только с USB модемом. Но тогда нужен компьютер.

Comment: А у вас СМС через телефон _бесплатные_?)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Есть за малую оплату безлимитно СМС можно отправлять. не по стандартному цену, а за абон. плату